# Why is Bitcoin Core not filling in PSBT_GLOBAL_XPUB field

Tags: bitcoin-core, bip174-psbt

When creating a Partially Signed Bitcoin Transaction (PSBT) on Bitcoin Core using the walletcreatefundedpsbt, walletprocesspsbt and send* RPCs, as well as the send dialog* in the GUI the PSBT_GLOBAL_XPUB field (defined in [BIP 174](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0174.mediawiki)) is not populated. Is there a reason for this omission?